# Text-based Tetris game CRTP 3

Tags: c++, c++11, game, design-patterns, tetris

Previous question:

[Text-based Tetris game with CRTP - follow-up 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75037/text-based-tetris-game-crtp-2)

Summary of improvements:

- Fixed Issues preventing the code from compiling on Clang
- Implemented helper class `range_impl`
- Removed all `std::initializer_list`
- Elimination of magic numbers

How can I improve this code further?

#### Tetris.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>

#include "rlutil.h"

using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

struct Point2D
{
    int x, y;
};

namespace
{
    enum Field
    {
        EMPTY = 0,
        WALL  = 9
    };

    enum Menu
    {
        PLAY = 1,
        EXIT = 0
    };

    enum Block_Edges
    {
        FROM = 0,
        TO   = 4,
    };

    enum Column_Edges 
    {
        CE_FROM  = 0,
        CE_TO    = 21
    };

    enum Row_Edges 
    {
        RE_FROM  = 0,
        RE_TO    = 12
    };

    template<typename T, bool enable = std::is_enum<T>::value>
    T& operator++(T& e)
    {
        return e = static_cast<T>(e + 1);
    }
};

template<typename T, bool enable = std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value>
struct range_impl
{
    struct iterator
    {
        const T operator * () const noexcept
        { 
            return value;
        }

        iterator& operator ++() noexcept
        { 
            ++value;
            return *this; 
        }

        friend  const bool operator != (const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs) noexcept
        {
            return lhs.value != rhs.value;
        }

        T value;
    };

    std::size_t size() const
    { 
        return last - first;
    }

    const iterator begin() const noexcept
    {
        return{ first };
    }

    const iterator end() const noexcept
    {
        return{ last };
    }

    T first;
    T last;
};

template<typename T>
struct range_impl<T, false>
{
    range_impl(T first, T last)
        : first(first)
        , last(last)
    {}

    std::size_t size() const
    { 
        return std::distance(first, last);
    }

    const T begin() const noexcept
    { 
        return{ first };
    }

    const T end() const noexcept
    {
        return{ last };
    }

    T first;
    T last;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2> 
range_impl<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>
range(T1 first, T2 last) noexcept
{
    return{ first, last };
}

class Shape
{
public:
    Shape() = default;

    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    virtual Shape *clone() const = 0;
    virtual int getDot(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const = 0;
    virtual Matrix rotate() = 0;
    virtual Matrix& shape() = 0;

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO).size();
    }
};


template <typename Derived>
struct Interfaceable : public Shape
{
    virtual Shape *clone() const override
    {
        return new Derived(static_cast<const Derived&>(*this));
    }

    virtual int getDot(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const override
    {
        return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this).shape[i][j];
    }

    virtual Matrix rotate() override
    {
        for (const auto i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
        {
            for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
            {
                if (i < j)
                {
                    std::swap(static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape[i][j], static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape[j][i]);
                }
            }

            std::reverse(static_cast< Derived&>(*this).shape[i].begin(), static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape[i].end());
        }

        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape;
    }

    virtual Matrix& shape() override
    {
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape;
    }
};

namespace shapes
{
    class O : public Interfaceable<O>
    {
    public:
        O() = default;
        virtual ~O() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class L : public Interfaceable<L>
    {
    public:
        L() = default;
        virtual ~L() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class M : public Interfaceable<M>
    {
    public:
        M() = default;
        virtual ~M() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class N : public Interfaceable<N>
    {
    public:
        N() = default;
        virtual ~N() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class T : public Interfaceable<T>
    {
    public:
        T() = default;
        virtual ~T() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class I : public Interfaceable<I>
    {
    public:
        I() = default;
        virtual ~I() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class S : public Interfaceable<S>
    {
    public:
        S() = default;
        virtual ~S() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };
};

class NonCopyable
{
public:
    NonCopyable() = default;
    virtual ~NonCopyable() = default;

    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = (const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};

class Tetris : private NonCopyable
{
public:
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Shape>;

    Tetris();

    void moveBlock(std::size_t, std::size_t);
    bool isCollide(std::size_t, std::size_t);
    void spawnBlock();
    bool applyRotate();
    bool isFull();

    Point2D getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }

private:
    void initField();
    void makeBlocks();
    void checkLine();
    void makeSolid();

    Matrix mStage;

    Point2D position;

    Shape *shape;

    void draw(std::ostream& stream) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Tetris& self)
    {
        self.draw(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    int blockType = 0;
    int mScore = 0;
    Matrix mBoard;

    std::minstd_rand rndEngine;

    std::vector<Ptr> shapes;

    std::size_t columnSize() const
    {
        return range(Column_Edges::CE_FROM, Column_Edges::CE_TO).size();
    }

    std::size_t rowSize() const
    {
        return range(Row_Edges::RE_FROM, Row_Edges::RE_TO).size();
    }

};

Tetris::Tetris()
{
    mBoard.resize(columnSize(), std::vector<int>(rowSize(), 0));
    mStage.resize(columnSize(), std::vector<int>(rowSize(), 0));

    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::T>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::M>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::N>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::I>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::O>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::L>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::S>()->clone()));

    initField();
}

void Tetris::initField()
{
    for (const auto& i : range(Column_Edges::CE_FROM, Column_Edges::CE_TO - 1)) 
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Row_Edges::RE_FROM, Row_Edges::RE_TO - 1))
        {
            if ((j == 0) || (j == rowSize() - 2) || (i == columnSize() - 2))
            {
                mBoard[i][j] = mStage[i][j] = WALL;
            }
            else
            {
                mBoard[i][j] = mStage[i][j] = EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }

    makeBlocks();
}

void Tetris::makeBlocks()
{
    position.x = shape->size();
    position.y = 0;

    int shapeCounts = 7;

    blockType = rndEngine() % shapeCounts;

    shape = shapes[blockType].get();

    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
        {
            mBoard[i][j + shape->size()] += shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j);
        }
    }
}

bool Tetris::isFull()
{
    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
        {
            if (mBoard[i][j + shape->size()] > 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
void Tetris::moveBlock(std::size_t x2, std::size_t y2)
{

    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
        {
            mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] -= shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j);;
        }
    }

    position.x = x2;
    position.y = y2;

    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
        {
            mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] += shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j);
        }
    }
}

void Tetris::checkLine()
{
    std::copy(mBoard.begin(), mBoard.end(), mStage.begin());

    for (const auto& i : range(Column_Edges::CE_FROM + 1, Column_Edges::CE_TO - 2))
    {
        bool isCompeteLine = true;

        for (const auto& j : range(Row_Edges::RE_FROM + 1, Row_Edges::RE_TO - 1))
        {
            if (mStage[i][j] == 0)
            {
                isCompeteLine = false;
            }
        }

        if (isCompeteLine)
        {
            mScore += 10;

            for (const auto& k : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
            {
                std::copy(mStage[i - 1 - k].begin(), mStage[i - 1 - k].end(), mStage[i - k].begin());
            }
        }
    }

    std::copy(mStage.begin(), mStage.end(), mBoard.begin());
}

bool Tetris::isCollide(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
        {
            if (shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j) && mStage[y + i][x + j] != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Tetris::makeSolid()
{
    if (isCollide(position.x, position.y + 1))
    {
        for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
        {
            for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
            {
                if (shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j) != 0)
                {
                    mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] = WALL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bool Tetris::applyRotate()
{
    Matrix temp(shape->size(), std::vector<int>(shape->size(), 0));

    std::copy(shapes[blockType]->shape().begin(), shapes[blockType]->shape().end(), temp.begin());

    shape->rotate();

    if (isCollide(position.x, position.y))
    {
        std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), shapes[blockType]->shape().begin());

        return true;
    }

    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::FROM, Block_Edges::TO))
        {
            mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] -= temp[i][j];
            mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] += shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void Tetris::spawnBlock()
{
    if (!isCollide(position.x, position.y + 1))
    {
        moveBlock(position.x, position.y + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        makeSolid();
        checkLine();
        makeBlocks();
    }
}

void Tetris::draw(std::ostream& stream) const
{
    for (auto i : mBoard)
    {
        for (auto j : i)
        {
            switch (j)
            {
            case EMPTY:
                stream << ' ';
                break;
            case WALL:
                rlutil::setColor(rlutil::CYAN);
                stream << '@';
                break;
            default:
                if (blockType == 0)
                {
                    rlutil::setColor(rlutil::GREY);
                }
                else
                {
                    rlutil::setColor(blockType);
                }
                stream << '#';
                break;
            }
        }

        stream << '\n';
    }

    rlutil::setColor(rlutil::GREY);

    stream << "Score : " << mScore
        << "\n\narrow keys left: ["
        << static_cast<char>(27) << "]\t down:["
        << static_cast<char>(25) << "]\t right:["
        << static_cast<char>(26) << "]\t Rotation:["
        << static_cast<char>(24) << "]";
}

class Game : private NonCopyable
{
public:
    int menu();
    void gameLoop();
private:
    void introScreen();
    void userInput();
    void display();
    void gameOverScreen();

    Tetris tetris;
};

void Game::gameOverScreen()
{
    gotoxy(10, 10);
    rlutil::setColor(rlutil::RED);

    std::cout << "\n"
        " #####     #    #     # ####### ####### #     # ####### ######\n"
        "#     #   # #   ##   ## #       #     # #     # #       #     #\n"
        "#        #   #  # # # # #       #     # #     # #       #     #\n"
        "#  #### #     # #  #  # #####   #     # #     # #####   ######\n"
        "#     # ####### #     # #       #     #  #   #  #       #   #\n"
        "#     # #     # #     # #       #     #   # #   #       #    #\n"
        " #####  #     # #     # ####### #######    #    ####### #     #\n"
        "\n\nPress enter to exit\n";

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
}

void Game::gameLoop()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    while (!tetris.isFull())
    {
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        double timeTakenInSeconds = (end - start).count()
            * (static_cast<double>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num)
            / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);

        if (kbhit())
        {
            userInput();
        }

        if (timeTakenInSeconds > 0.3)
        {
            tetris.spawnBlock();
            display();
            start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        }
    }

    rlutil::cls();

    gameOverScreen();
}

int Game::menu()
{
    introScreen();

    int selectNum = 0;

    std::cin >> selectNum;

    switch (selectNum)
    {
    case PLAY:
    case EXIT:
        break;
    default:
        selectNum = 0;
        break;
    }

    return selectNum;
}

void Game::introScreen()
{
    rlutil::cls();
    std::cout << "#==============================================================================#\n"
        "####### ####### ####### ######    ###    #####\n"
        "   #    #          #    #     #    #    #     #\n"
        "   #    #          #    #     #    #    #\n"
        "   #    #####      #    ######     #     #####\n"
        "   #    #          #    #   #      #          #\n"
        "   #    #          #    #    #     #    #     #\n"
        "   #    #######    #    #     #   ###    #####\t\tmade for fun \n"
        "\n\n\n\n"

        "\t<Menu>\n"
        "\t1: Start Game\n\t2: Quit\n\n"
        "#==============================================================================#\n"
        "Choose >> ";
}

void Game::display()
{
    rlutil::cls();

    std::cout << tetris;
}

void Game::userInput()
{
    const int k = rlutil::getkey();
    switch (k)
    {
    case rlutil::KEY_RIGHT:
        if (!tetris.isCollide(tetris.getPosition().x + 1, tetris.getPosition().y))
        {
            tetris.moveBlock(tetris.getPosition().x + 1, tetris.getPosition().y);
        }
        break;
    case rlutil::KEY_LEFT:
        if (!tetris.isCollide(tetris.getPosition().x - 1, tetris.getPosition().y))
        {
            tetris.moveBlock(tetris.getPosition().x - 1, tetris.getPosition().y);
        }
        break;
    case rlutil::KEY_DOWN:
        if (!tetris.isCollide(tetris.getPosition().x, tetris.getPosition().y + 1))
        {
            tetris.moveBlock(tetris.getPosition().x, tetris.getPosition().y + 1);
        }
        break;
    case rlutil::KEY_UP:
        tetris.applyRotate();
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;

    switch (game.menu())
    {
    case PLAY:
        game.gameLoop();
        break;
    case EXIT:
        return 0;
    default:
        std::cerr << "Choose 1~2" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

[rhutil.h](https://gist.github.com/MORTAL2000/0a1dbc256220b58fa1dc)

[Strong type enum version](https://github.com/MORTAL2000/Text-based-Tetris-cross-Platform-CRTP/blob/master/tetris-strong%20type%20enum-version.cpp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`enum class`](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum). Instead of encoding the type of an enum such as `RE_FROM` and `CE_FROM` write something like this:

```
enum class Block_Edges
{
    from = 0,
    to   = 4,
};

enum class Column_Edges 
{
    from  = 0,
    to    = 21
};

enum class Row_Edges 
{
    from  = 0,
    to    = 12
};
```

Now you get more type checking and have less repetitive typing to do (`Column_Edges::from` instead of `Column_Edges::CE_FROM`). I did not capitalize `from` because it is not a macro-ish constant anymore.

A side effect of this is that you cannot do `Row_Edges::from + 1` anymore because `enum class` does not decay into an `int` like `enum` does. Instead you can define addition and subtraction operations such as this:

```
int operator+(const Row_Edges &re, int i)
{
    const int rei = i + static_cast<int>(re);
    if (rei < static_cast<int>(Row_Edges::from) || rei > static_cast<int>(Row_Edges::to))
        throw std::out_of_range("Addition to Row_Edges would create out of bounds index");
    return rei;
}
```

You can now add `int`s to `Row_Edges` with optional runtime checks.

Comment: i don't think this will work. i have tried strong type enum before but VC++ won't compile it.

Comment: @MORTAL I tested the code in Visual Studio Express 2013 update 4 and it worked fine.

Comment: You had some small errors in your code (`#include <exception>` instead of `#include <stdexcept>`, missing `#include <type_traits>`, confusing `FROM` with `from`, wrong operator, mixing enums and `int`s). Try [this one](http://ideone.com/gabRH4). Also adding operators for all `enum class`es is not a good idea.

Comment: sorry for that link it wasn't the code i meant it. i'm working on code hopefully i will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

@nwp is right and very right when he says

> the problem with enum class does not decay into an int like enum does

the generic functions for letting enum class accept`Row_Edges::from + 1` and `Row_Edges::from - 1` would be like this

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, bool enable = std::is_enum<T1>::value>
auto operator+(const T1& e1, const T2& e2) 
    -> decltype(static_cast<int>(e1) + static_cast<int>(e2))
{
    auto result = static_cast<int>(e1) + static_cast<int>(e2);

    if (result < static_cast<int>(T1::from) || result > static_cast<int>(T1::to))
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("subtration to enum would create out of bounds index");
    }

    return  result;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, bool enable = std::is_enum<T1>::value>
auto operator-(const T1& e1, const T2& e2)
    -> decltype(static_cast<int>(e1) - static_cast<int>(e2))
{
    auto result = static_cast<int>(e1) - static_cast<int>(e2);

    if (result < static_cast<int>(T1::from) || result > static_cast<int>(T1::to))
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("subtration to enum would create out of bounds index");
    }

    return  result;
}
```

however, it has drawback when it needed to be assign to vector `mStage[i][j] = static_cast<int>(Field::wall)`. To over come this we need to treat enum class by its underlying type throughout the code. to achieve this we need to declare new function class `make_integer()`

```
template <typename Enumeration>
auto make_integer(const Enumeration& value)
    -> typename std::underlying_type<Enumeration>::type
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum<Enumeration>::value, "parameter is not of type enum or enum class");
    return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<Enumeration>::type>(value);
}
```

no need for `auto operator-(const T1& e1, const T2& e2)`and `auto operator-(const T1& e1, const T2& e2)`. we can apply arithmetic operations like this `make_integer(Row_Edges::to) - 1` and `mStage[i][j] = make_integer(Field::wall)`. but still we need to casting with switch statements.

**Solution**

to over come the encoding the type of an enum. it can be done by namespace of unknown enum like this

```
namespace Field
{
    enum
    {
        empty = 0,
        wall = 9
    };
}

namespace Menu
{
    enum
    {
        play = 1,
        exit = 0
    };
}

namespace Block_Edges
{
    enum
    {
        from = 0,
        to   = 4,
    };
}

namespace Column_Edges
{
    enum
    {
        from = 0,
        to   = 21
    };
}

namespace Row_Edges
{
    enum
    {
        from = 0,
        to   = 12
    };
}
```

advantages of this method, it allows the overloading the arithmetic operators like `Row_Edges::from + 1` and `Row_Edges::from - 1`. Also, it allows the value of the enum type to be as constant that would be much easier and no need for casting in `switch` statements and `=` assign it to vector's elements later on.

**complete code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>

#include "rlutil.h"

using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

struct Point2D
{
    int x, y;
};

namespace Field
{
    enum
    {
        empty = 0,
        wall = 9
    };
}

namespace Menu
{
    enum
    {
        play = 1,
        exit = 0
    };
}

namespace Block_Edges
{
    enum
    {
        from = 0,
        to   = 4,
    };
}

namespace Column_Edges
{
    enum
    {
        from = 0,
        to   = 21
    };
}

namespace Row_Edges
{
    enum
    {
        from = 0,
        to   = 12
    };
}

template<typename Enumeration, bool enable = std::is_enum<Enumeration>::value>
Enumeration& operator++(Enumeration& e)
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum<Enumeration>::value, "parameter is not of type enum or enum class");
    return e = static_cast<typename Enumeration>(e + 1);
}

template<typename T, bool enable = std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value>
struct range_impl
{
    struct iterator
    {
        const T operator * () const noexcept
        {
            return value;
        }

            iterator& operator ++() noexcept
        {
            ++value;
            return *this;
        }

            friend  const bool operator != (const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs) noexcept
        {
            return lhs.value != rhs.value;
        }

        T value;
    };

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return last - first;
    }

    const iterator begin() const noexcept
    {
        return{ first };
    }

        const iterator end() const noexcept
    {
        return{ last };
    }

    T first;
    T last;
};

template<typename T>
struct range_impl<T, false>
{
    range_impl(T first, T last)
        : first(first)
        , last(last)
    {}

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return std::distance(first, last);
    }

    const T begin() const noexcept
    {
        return{ first };
    }

        const T end() const noexcept
    {
        return{ last };
    }

    T first;
    T last;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
range_impl<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> range(T1 first, T2 last) noexcept
{
    return{ first, last };
}

class Shape
{
public:
    Shape() = default;

    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    virtual Shape *clone() const = 0;
    virtual int getDot(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const = 0;
    virtual Matrix rotate() = 0;
    virtual Matrix& shape() = 0;

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to).size();
    }
};


template <typename Derived>
struct Interfaceable : public Shape
{
    virtual Shape *clone() const override
    {
        return new Derived(static_cast<const Derived&>(*this));
    }

    virtual int getDot(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const override
    {
        return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this).shape[i][j];
    }

    virtual Matrix rotate() override
    {
        for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
        {
            for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
            {
                if (i < j)
                {
                    std::swap(static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape[i][j], static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape[j][i]);
                }
            }

            std::reverse(static_cast< Derived&>(*this).shape[i].begin(), static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape[i].end());
        }

        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape;
    }

    virtual Matrix& shape() override
    {
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).shape;
    }
};

namespace shapes
{
    class O : public Interfaceable<O>
    {
    public:
        O() = default;
        virtual ~O() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class L : public Interfaceable<L>
    {
    public:
        L() = default;
        virtual ~L() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class M : public Interfaceable<M>
    {
    public:
        M() = default;
        virtual ~M() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class N : public Interfaceable<N>
    {
    public:
        N() = default;
        virtual ~N() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class T : public Interfaceable<T>
    {
    public:
        T() = default;
        virtual ~T() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class I : public Interfaceable<I>
    {
    public:
        I() = default;
        virtual ~I() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };

    class S : public Interfaceable<S>
    {
    public:
        S() = default;
        virtual ~S() = default;

        Matrix shape
        {
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0 }
            }
        };
    };
};

class NonCopyable
{
public:
    NonCopyable() = default;
    virtual ~NonCopyable() = default;

    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = (const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};

class Tetris : private NonCopyable
{
public:
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Shape>;

    Tetris();

    void moveBlock(std::size_t, std::size_t);
    bool isCollide(std::size_t, std::size_t);
    void spawnBlock();
    bool applyRotate();
    bool isFull();

    Point2D getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }

private:
    void initField();
    void makeBlocks();
    void checkLine();
    void makeSolid();

    Matrix mStage;

    Point2D position;

    Shape *shape;

    void draw(std::ostream& stream) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Tetris& self)
    {
        self.draw(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    int blockType = 0;
    int mScore = 0;
    Matrix mBoard;

    std::minstd_rand rndEngine;

    std::vector<Ptr> shapes;

    std::size_t columnSize() const
    {
        return range(Column_Edges::from, Column_Edges::to).size();
    }

    std::size_t rowSize() const
    {
        return range(Row_Edges::from, Row_Edges::to).size();
    }

};

Tetris::Tetris()
{
    mBoard.resize(columnSize(), std::vector<int>(rowSize(), 0));
    mStage.resize(columnSize(), std::vector<int>(rowSize(), 0));

    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::T>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::M>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::N>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::I>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::O>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::L>()->clone()));
    shapes.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<shapes::S>()->clone()));

    initField();
}

void Tetris::initField()
{
    for (const auto& i : range(Column_Edges::from, Column_Edges::to - 1))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Row_Edges::from, Row_Edges::to - 1))
        {
            if ((j == 0) || (j == rowSize() - 2) || (i == columnSize() - 2))
            {
                mBoard[i][j] = mStage[i][j] = Field::wall;
            }
            else
            {
                mBoard[i][j] = mStage[i][j] = Field::empty;
            }
        }
    }

    makeBlocks();
}

void Tetris::makeBlocks()
{
    position.x = shape->size();
    position.y = 0;

    int shapeCounts = 7;

    blockType = rndEngine() % shapeCounts;

    shape = shapes[blockType].get();

    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
        {
            mBoard[i][j + shape->size()] += shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j);
        }
    }
}

bool Tetris::isFull()
{
    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
        {
            if (mBoard[i][j + shape->size()] > 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
void Tetris::moveBlock(std::size_t x2, std::size_t y2)
{

    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
        {
            mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] -= shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j);;
        }
    }

    position.x = x2;
    position.y = y2;

    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
        {
            mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] += shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j);
        }
    }
}

void Tetris::checkLine()
{
    std::copy(mBoard.begin(), mBoard.end(), mStage.begin());

    for (const auto& i : range(Column_Edges::from + 1, Column_Edges::to - 2))
    {
        bool isCompeteLine = true;

        for (const auto& j : range(Row_Edges::from + 1, Row_Edges::to - 1))
        {
            if (mStage[i][j] == 0)
            {
                isCompeteLine = false;
            }
        }

        if (isCompeteLine)
        {
            mScore += 10;

            for (const auto& k : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
            {
                std::copy(mStage[i - 1 - k].begin(), mStage[i - 1 - k].end(), mStage[i - k].begin());
            }
        }
    }

    std::copy(mStage.begin(), mStage.end(), mBoard.begin());
}

bool Tetris::isCollide(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
        {
            if (shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j) && mStage[y + i][x + j] != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Tetris::makeSolid()
{
    if (isCollide(position.x, position.y + 1))
    {
        for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
        {
            for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
            {
                if (shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j) != 0)
                {
                    mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] = static_cast<int>(Field::wall);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bool Tetris::applyRotate()
{
    Matrix temp(shape->size(), std::vector<int>(shape->size(), 0));

    std::copy(shapes[blockType]->shape().begin(), shapes[blockType]->shape().end(), temp.begin());

    shape->rotate();

    if (isCollide(position.x, position.y))
    {
        std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), shapes[blockType]->shape().begin());

        return true;
    }

    for (const auto& i : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
    {
        for (const auto& j : range(Block_Edges::from, Block_Edges::to))
        {
            mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] -= temp[i][j];
            mBoard[position.y + i][position.x + j] += shapes[blockType]->getDot(i, j);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void Tetris::spawnBlock()
{
    if (!isCollide(position.x, position.y + 1))
    {
        moveBlock(position.x, position.y + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        makeSolid();
        checkLine();
        makeBlocks();
    }
}

void Tetris::draw(std::ostream& stream) const
{
    for (auto i : mBoard)
    {
        for (auto j : i)
        {
            switch (j)
            {
            case Field::empty:
                stream << ' ';
                break;
            case Field::wall:
                rlutil::setColor(rlutil::CYAN);
                stream << '@';
                break;
            default:
                if (blockType == 0)
                {
                    rlutil::setColor(rlutil::GREY);
                }
                else
                {
                    rlutil::setColor(blockType);
                }
                stream << '#';
                break;
            }
        }

        stream << '\n';
    }

    rlutil::setColor(rlutil::GREY);

    stream << "Score : " << mScore
        << "\n\narrow keys left: ["
        << static_cast<char>(27) << "]\t down:["
        << static_cast<char>(25) << "]\t right:["
        << static_cast<char>(26) << "]\t Rotation:["
        << static_cast<char>(24) << "]";
}

class Game : private NonCopyable
{
public:
    int menu();
    void gameLoop();
private:
    void introScreen();
    void userInput();
    void display();
    void gameOverScreen();

    Tetris tetris;
};

void Game::gameOverScreen()
{
    gotoxy(10, 10);
    rlutil::setColor(rlutil::RED);

    std::cout << "\n"
        " #####     #    #     # ####### ####### #     # ####### ######\n"
        "#     #   # #   ##   ## #       #     # #     # #       #     #\n"
        "#        #   #  # # # # #       #     # #     # #       #     #\n"
        "#  #### #     # #  #  # #####   #     # #     # #####   ######\n"
        "#     # ####### #     # #       #     #  #   #  #       #   #\n"
        "#     # #     # #     # #       #     #   # #   #       #    #\n"
        " #####  #     # #     # ####### #######    #    ####### #     #\n"
        "\n\nPress enter to exit\n";

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
}

void Game::gameLoop()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    while (!tetris.isFull())
    {
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        double timeTakenInSeconds = (end - start).count()
            * (static_cast<double>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num)
            / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);

        if (kbhit())
        {
            userInput();
        }

        if (timeTakenInSeconds > 0.3)
        {
            tetris.spawnBlock();
            display();
            start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        }
    }

    rlutil::cls();

    gameOverScreen();
}

int Game::menu()
{
    introScreen();

    int selectNum = 0;

    std::cin >> selectNum;

    switch (selectNum)
    {
    case Menu::play:
    case Menu::exit:
        break;
    default:
        selectNum = 0;
        break;
    }

    return selectNum;
}

void Game::introScreen()
{
    rlutil::cls();
    std::cout << "#==============================================================================#\n"
        "####### ####### ####### ######    ###    #####\n"
        "   #    #          #    #     #    #    #     #\n"
        "   #    #          #    #     #    #    #\n"
        "   #    #####      #    ######     #     #####\n"
        "   #    #          #    #   #      #          #\n"
        "   #    #          #    #    #     #    #     #\n"
        "   #    #######    #    #     #   ###    #####\t\tmade for fun \n"
        "\n\n\n\n"

        "\t<Menu>\n"
        "\t1: Start Game\n\t2: Quit\n\n"
        "#==============================================================================#\n"
        "Choose >> ";
}

void Game::display()
{
    rlutil::cls();

    std::cout << tetris;
}

void Game::userInput()
{
    const int k = rlutil::getkey();
    switch (k)
    {
    case rlutil::KEY_RIGHT:
        if (!tetris.isCollide(tetris.getPosition().x + 1, tetris.getPosition().y))
        {
            tetris.moveBlock(tetris.getPosition().x + 1, tetris.getPosition().y);
        }
        break;
    case rlutil::KEY_LEFT:
        if (!tetris.isCollide(tetris.getPosition().x - 1, tetris.getPosition().y))
        {
            tetris.moveBlock(tetris.getPosition().x - 1, tetris.getPosition().y);
        }
        break;
    case rlutil::KEY_DOWN:
        if (!tetris.isCollide(tetris.getPosition().x, tetris.getPosition().y + 1))
        {
            tetris.moveBlock(tetris.getPosition().x, tetris.getPosition().y + 1);
        }
        break;
    case rlutil::KEY_UP:
        tetris.applyRotate();
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;

    switch (game.menu())
    {
    case Menu::play:
        game.gameLoop();
        break;
    case Menu::exit:
        return 0;
    default:
        std::cerr << "Choose 1~2" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```